# Validate valid certificate with attribute PSEUDONYM

Tags: java, x509certificate

At the moment I'm receiving messages which are signed with a certificate.
So far so good.
However the certificate contains an attribute PSEUDONYM. 
Now the Java runtime doesn't accept it. I get an IO Exception. (When I remove the PSEUDONYM exception is gone ) 
Does anybody know you to validate these messages as i'm sure that attribute PSEUDONYM is allowed.
C=DE,O=InfoCompany,OU=SoftwareMe,CN=SIGNER,SERIALNUMBER=1,PSEUDONYM=SIGNER

Any ideas how to change the default java validation to allow the PSEUDONYM tag?

Comment: bouncycastle? Since maybe java don't support this attribute, you could change to a 3rd party implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using constructor `X500Principal(String name, Map<String,String> keywordMap)` allows you to specify custom RDNs in keywordMap. The map's key is a RDN name and the value is a string representation of OID. See [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.html#X500Principal%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) for details.